# MySQL cascade deleting for one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql database with a lot of tables. Each table has InnoDB format.
I have a table called "companies". Each company has an account, account has transactions and there are lots of other related tables.

I want to delete some companies and all data related to them.
Each foreign key has "NO ACTION" on delete event.

How could I temporary delete all relations without manually setting ON DELETE CASCADE for each foreign key?

Comment: Too many tables. Really, a company has users, a user has pictures, company also has account, account has transactions and a much more relations. I'm just too lazy to join half database :) I decided to change no action to cascade delete, much faster. But I thought there is a way to "temporary enable casacade deleting" or kind of

Comment: Well there is! But you're too lazy to do it! :-)

Comment: Not just a matter of laziness, but also future-proofing. Doing it with explicit joins would mean your delete script has to be updated every time you change your schema.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change fk on delete compartament you will do something like this

```
ALTER TABLE `table1`  
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_name` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`fk_table2_id`) REFERENCES `table2` (`t2`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```